# How to configure nginx to add a query parameter only when the requested uri is / and the specific query parameter doesn't already exist?

Tags: nginx

Suppose the query parameter I'm interested in is `arg1=val1`.  I would like nginx to add the query parameter only when the requested uri is `/` and the query parameter `arg1` doesn't already exist.  Expected behavior is illustrated as below:

requested:

```
/
```

expected to be passed to backend:

```
/?arg1=val1
```

---

requested:

```
/?arg2=val2
```

expected to be passed to backend:

```
/?arg1=val1&arg2=val2
```

---

requested:

```
/path1
```

expected to be passed to backend (don't add the parameter if the requested uri is not `/`):

```
/path1
```

---

requested:

```
/?arg1=valx&arg2=val2
```

expected to be passed to backend (if the parameter already exists, don't change its value):

```
/?arg1=valx&arg2=val2
```

---

What I've tried in `nginx.conf` is as below:

```
location / {
    if ($args !~ ^(.*)(arg1=)(.*)$) {
        rewrite ^(/)$ /?arg1=val1 last;
    }

    ......
}
```

And it doesn't work as expected.

How should I configure `nginx` to achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: What does "doesn't work as expected" mean? What did it do?

Answer (score 2):

To match only / use =. Try

```
location = / {
    if ($args = "") {
        set $args arg1=val1;
        # or rewrite / /?arg1=val1 last;
    }
    if ($args !~ "arg1=") {
        set $args $args&arg1=val1;
    }
}
```

You can get debug output showing you how nginx is handling your directives 
by putting in your server{} block:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
```